# Sudo apt-get update in raspberry pi is not working after raspbian updates & folder structure change in http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-22.04

Since recently i am facing an issue with sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade, There is an official updates from http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/

Issue is listed below

santhosh@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
libgnutls30 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnss3 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 sox
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libgnutls30 armhf 3.7.1-5+deb11u3
Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I tried by editing the /ect/apt/source.list file by replacing

**from**
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi

**To**
http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye main contrib non-free rpi

It updates few packages but again it start to through the error's like
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye/dists/main/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages

looking for solution to resolve this issue

Regards
Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

--change file permission of sources.list file in /etc/apt using chmod 777.
--put ## in front of present repository in /etc/apt/sources.list.
--add  deb http://ftp.crifo.org/raspbian/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi   to sources.list.
-- save sources.list .

Comment: This link did not work!

Answer (score 1):

Open source.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list
```

comment the current line by adding # in the front of the line, it would be something like this after adding comment to the line:

```
#deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
```

then add at the end of the file:

```
deb http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
```

After that ctrl+s to save the changes
now update

```
sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

This worked for me!

source:https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349973

Comment: I was installing Java 11 for OpenHAB on my RaspberryPI. I found your solution which helped me. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

`sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list` did not work. What did was:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).